# Class does not implement Interface and code still compiles

Tags: c#, interface

I need to create a custom collection that implements IBindingList in order to be able to bind it with a custom control from 3rd party. Another problem that I have is that I have to make that collection thread safe because I manually insert items from multiple threads simultaneously.

Anyways I am using a `BindingList<T>` as a field on my class in order to don't reinvent the wheel to much. So my class looks like:

```
class ThreadSaveBindingCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IBindingList
{
    BindingList<T> collection;
    object _lock = new object();

    // constructors
    public ThreadSaveBindingCollection(IEnumerable<T> initialCollection)
    {
        if (initialCollection == null)
            collection = new BindingList<T>();
        else                            
            collection = new BindingList<T>(new List<T>(initialCollection));                                 
    }
    public ThreadSaveBindingCollection() : this(null)
    {            
    }   

    // Todo: Implement interfaces using collection to do the work    
}
```

Note I am missing to implement the interface IEnumerable and IBinding list. **I am planning for the field `collection` to take care of that as it implements those interfaces as well**. So I let visual studio implement the interface explicitly and replace the `throw new NotImplementedException()` with the field `collection` implementation and I end up with something like:

[image]

### Now the question is

**Why I cannot call the method AddIndex on the field collection if collection claims to implement IBindingList!?**

[image]

**I am not able to do the same thing for several of the methods**

Comment: It looks like your second code block is missing. Can you make sure all of the relevant code is in your question?

Comment: Cast to IBindingList, then call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because it's an explicit implementation of the interface, rather than implicit. This means you must call it through the interface rather than the type itself. For example:

```
((IBindingList)collection).AddIndex(property);
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) for more information on explicit interface implementations.

Answer (score 1):

It is implemented explicity by `BindingList`, you need to cast your reference of `collection` to `IBindingList` to use it:

```
(collection as IBindingList).AddIndex(property);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx

[Further reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

The point of explicit implementation and access via a reference of the interface itself is to resolve naming conflicts where two parties create two separate interfaces with the same method signatures - it allows you to disambiguate the methods whilst still implementing both interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

`BindingList` explicitly implements `IBindingList`, so you need to do

```
(collection as IBindingList).AddIndex(property);
```